# repair exchange after removing domain controller

Tags: active-directory, iis-7, exchange-2010, domain-controller

I had exchange 2010 installed on a domain controller {same host} (I know). I installed a second domain controller on the domain removed the DC installed on the same machine as exchange 2010. This is where my problems are. Now exchange still functions as a mail server but in the management console i keep getting IIS related errors and things half load.

I am aware now that there are ways to remove DC from exchange machine without having these problems but it happened.

How do i repair my Exchange farm so i stop getting error messages (I think because it is still binded to old domain controller)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to DC Promo it (make it a DC again) and then you can use the steps you have learned to remove DC from exchange without those problems. Alternately you can leave Exchange as a DC. It used to be not such a problem in the past when there was a concept of primary and secondary servers. But now since any DC can be considered a "Primary" you may not want that additional load on your exchange server.

Comment: I will use DC Promo then remove DC properly. See if it works then post back. TBH i should have done this already.

Comment: I tried to install DC again & got this error message when i ran dcpromo.

The operation failed because:

Active Directory Domain Services could not create the NTDS Settings object for this Active Directory Domain Controller CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC1,CN=Servers,CN=Manukau,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=AccessGroupnz,DC=com on the remote AD DC Server1.AccessGroupnz.com. Ensure the provided network credentials have sufficient permissions.

"The DSA operation is unable to proceed because of a DNS lookup failure."

I think this is the same reason i got errors in exchange.